# MongoDB query with multiple conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have data with multiple documents :

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("57b68dbbc19c0bd86d62e486"),
 "empId" : "1"
 "type" : "WebUser",
 "city" : "Pune"
}
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("57b68dbbc19c0bd86d62e487"),
 "empId" : "2"
 "type" : "Admin",
 "city" : "Mumbai"
}
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("57b68dbbc19c0bd86d62e488"),
 "empId" : "3"
 "type" : "Admin",
 "city" : "Pune"
}
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("57b68dbbc19c0bd86d62e489"),
 "empId" : "4"
 "type" : "User",
 "city" : "Mumbai"
}
```

I want to get data according to my multiple conditions :

```
condition 1:- {"type" : "WebUser", "city" : "Pune"}

condition 2:- {"type" : "WebUser", "city" : "Pune"} & {"type" : "User", "city" : "Mumbai"}
```

I want below result when run condition 1 :

```
    {
     "_id" : ObjectId("57b68dbbc19c0bd86d62e486"),
     "empId" : "1"
     "type" : "WebUser",
     "city" : "Pune"
    }
```

When I run second condition :

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("57b68dbbc19c0bd86d62e486"),
  "empId" : "1"
  "type" : "WebUser",
  "city" : "Pune"
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("57b68dbbc19c0bd86d62e489"),
  "empId" : "4"
  "type" : "User",
  "city" : "Mumbai"
}
```

I want above result by one query,

Currently I am using below aggregate query,

```
 db.emp.aggregate([
     { $match: { '$and': [
         {"type" : "WebUser", "city" : "Pune"}, 
         {"type" : "User", "city" : "Mumbai"}
     ] } },
     { $group: { _id: 1, ids: { $push: "$empId" } } }
 ])
```

Above query work for first condition & fails for other. Please help me.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For the second condition, you can use the **[`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)** operator in your query as:

```
db.emp.find({
    "type" : { "$in": ["WebUser", "User"] },
    "city" : { "$in": ["Pune", "Mumbai"] }
})
```

If you want to use in aggregation:

```
 db.emp.aggregate([
     { 
        "$match": {
            "type" : { "$in": ["WebUser", "User"] },
            "city" : { "$in": ["Pune", "Mumbai"] }
        }
     },
     { "$group": { "_id": null, "ids": { "$push": "$empId" } } }
 ])
```

or simply use the [**`distinct()`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) method to return an array of distinct empIds that match the above query as:

```
var employeeIds = db.emp.distinct("empId", {
    "type" : { "$in": ["WebUser", "User"] },
    "city" : { "$in": ["Pune", "Mumbai"] }
});
```

Comment: Above query work as "OR" condition. I need "AND". i.e. Result only return on exact match of both condition.

Comment: The comma operator behaves as an $and implicity.

Answer (score 28):

If you are looking for the AND operator

This example checks if a field exists **AND** is null

```
db.getCollection('TheCollection').find({
    $and: [
        {'the_key': { $exists: true }},
        {'the_key': null}
    ]
})
```

This example checks if a field has 'value1' **OR** 'value2'

```
db.getCollection('TheCollection').find({
    $or: [
        {'the_key': 'value1'},
        {`the_key': 'value2'}
    ]
})
```

When just checking for null, the return contains non-existing fields plus fields with value null

```
db.getCollection('TheCollection').find({'the_key': null})
```

Comment: -1 `db.getCollection('TheCollection').find({ 'the_key': 'value1', 'the_key': 'value2' })` will evaluate to `db.getCollection('TheCollection').find({ 'the_key': 'value2' })` because javascript will not allow an object with two keys using same name. Also, mongoDB will evaluate multiple parameters as `AND` logic, not `OR`.

Comment: I thought I tested and it worked but anyway. I edited it. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 11):

You can use mongo db `$or` operator.

```
    db.emp.find({ $or: [
      { "type": "WebUser", "city": "Pune" },
      { "type": "user", "city": "Mumbai"}
    ]})
```

You  can pass conditions in the array.

For more reference [see mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Display the document where in the “StudName” has value “Ajay Rathod”.

   > db.Student.find({name:"ajay rathod"})

   ```
   { "_id" : ObjectId("5fdd895cd2d5a20ee8cea0de"), "
   ```
2. Retrieve only Student Name and Grade.

   > db.Student.find({},{name:1,grade:1,_id:0})

   ```
   { "name" : "dhruv", "grade" : "A" }
   { "name" : "jay", "grade" : "B" }
   { "name" : "abhi", "grade" : "C" }
   { "name" : "aayush", "grade" : "A" }
   { "name" : "sukhdev", "grade" : "B" }
   { "name" : "dhruval", "grade" : "B" }
   { "name" : "ajay rathod", "grade" : "D" }
   ```