# Find documents where field value matches an array element - MongoDB Native Driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, node-mongodb-native

I want to fetch all documents from a collection where a document property has the value of an array element.

For instance, I have a collection where all documents have a property named ".foreignKey" and I want to find all documents where .foreignKey matches one of the elements of an array named "foreignKeys".

The code that I have currently have looks like this:

```
const foreignKeys = [0,10,100,500]
const result = await getAppDatabase().collection("Collection")).find({
                   foreignKey: foreignKeys
               }).toArray()
```

Result must have documents where .foreignKey is either 0, 10, 100 or 500.

The code that I've provided does not work and I cannot seem to find an efficient solution to my problem. Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Try using the `$in` operator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB query with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39389823/mongodb-query-with-multiple-conditions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `$in` or `$or`

Recommendation is `$in` for your case

[Refer](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#-or-versus--in)

> When using $or with  that are equality checks for the value of the same field, use the $in operator instead of the $or operator.

```
await getAppDatabase().collection("Collection")).find({
       ".foreignKey": { "$in": foreignKeys}}).toArray()
```